# Connect to particular wifi in Android using Android library when wifi was disabled in phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wifi, android-wifi

I am working on Android application which involves connecting a particular WiFi SSID without password. Whenever user enters in the premises app detect a specific beacon via BLE. After that app try to connect a WiFi programmed in app code using WifiManager.
Here I am facing some issue:
1) If WiFi already disabled in phone - App enables WiFi and try to connect to already configured WiFi (may be alphabetic order). In this case it may connect another WiFi which is available and configured in phone instead of connection to my SSID.

2) If WiFi enabled in phone: If WiFi already enabled App reconnect to my SSID which is correct.

3) WiFi disabled and my SSID is not configured in phone. It wont connect to WiFi.

Cases 1 and 3 really headache. How I am doing in program please see the code:

```
// wifi
WifiManager wifiManager= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
// setup a wifi configuration
WifiConfiguration wc= new WifiConfiguration();
wc.SSID = "\"mySSID\"";

wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
try {
Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}

wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
// connect to and enable the connection

int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Comment: I guess you view WIFI being disabled in much the same way that most telemarketers view the "do not call" list.

Answer (score 0):

After your app detect beacon from BLE

- Turn ON/Enable Wifi, if its off.
- Disable all other network configuration except the one which has your "Wi-fi SSID". You should use the networkId to identify the configuration. API to disable configuration is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#disableNetwork(int) OR you can disable all other configuration while enabling your network using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#enableNetwork()
- You will be connected to your SSID if its available.

As a well behaved app, you should re-enable all the network configuration before the app exits.